# JavaScript innerHTML change onclick not working

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I want to change a piece of text with the click of a button, this doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
    <div>
        This text should stay, <span id="x">This text should change.</span>
    </div>
        <button type="button" onclick='change()'>Change</button>
            <script type="javascript/text">
                function change() {
                    document.getElementById('x').innerHTML='The text has changed.';
                }
            </script>
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">`, or just `<script>`

Comment: Just leave off the "type" attribute completely.

Comment: @JosiahKeller You should probably answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type attribute is wrong.  You don't really need it at all.  If you do want to include it, change it to `text/javascript`.